# How to retrain the last fully connected layer for a ssd mobilenet v2 model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tf-slim

I currently retrained an ssd mobile net v2 model using the [tutorial](https://youtube/JR8CmWyh2E8). I ran the following in command line to execute the retraining. It retrained the entire model.

```
(tensorflow) c:\models-master\research>python object_detection/legacy/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/model2/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v2_2.config
```

I set the config file as such:

```
# SSD with Mobilenet v2 configuration for MSCOCO Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 1
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
    matcher {
      argmax_matcher {
        matched_threshold: 0.5
        unmatched_threshold: 0.5
        ignore_thresholds: false
        negatives_lower_than_unmatched: true
        force_match_for_each_row: true
      }
    }
    similarity_calculator {
      iou_similarity {
      }
    }
    anchor_generator {
      ssd_anchor_generator {
        num_layers: 6
        min_scale: 0.2
        max_scale: 0.95
        aspect_ratios: 1.0
        aspect_ratios: 2.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.5
        aspect_ratios: 3.0
        aspect_ratios: 0.3333
      }
    }
    image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 300
        width: 300
      }
    }
    box_predictor {
      convolutional_box_predictor {
        min_depth: 0
        max_depth: 0
        num_layers_before_predictor: 0
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 0.8
        kernel_size: 3
        box_code_size: 4
        apply_sigmoid_to_scores: false
        conv_hyperparams {
          activation: RELU_6,
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.00004
            }
          }
          initializer {
            truncated_normal_initializer {
              stddev: 0.03
              mean: 0.0
            }
          }
          batch_norm {
            train: true,
            scale: true,
            center: true,
            decay: 0.9997,
            epsilon: 0.001,
          }
        }
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'ssd_mobilenet_v2'
      min_depth: 16
      depth_multiplier: 1.0
      use_depthwise: true
      conv_hyperparams {
        activation: RELU_6,
        regularizer {
          l2_regularizer {
            weight: 0.00004
          }
        }
        initializer {
          truncated_normal_initializer {
            stddev: 0.03
            mean: 0.0
          }
        }
        batch_norm {
          train: true,
          scale: true,
          center: true,
          decay: 0.9997,
          epsilon: 0.001,
        }
      }
    }
    loss {
      classification_loss {
        weighted_sigmoid {
        }
      }
      localization_loss {
        weighted_smooth_l1 {
        }
      }
      hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 3
      }
      classification_weight: 1.0
      localization_weight: 1.0
    }
    normalize_loss_by_num_matches: true
    post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 1e-8
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 100
      }
      score_converter: SIGMOID
    }
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 24
  optimizer {
    rms_prop_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        exponential_decay_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.004
          decay_steps: 800720
          decay_factor: 0.95
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
      decay: 0.9
      epsilon: 1.0
    }
  }
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "D:/Databases/Coco/cctv/tf/ssd_mobilenet_v2_coco_2018_03_29/model.ckpt"
  fine_tune_checkpoint_type:  "detection"
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 200000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
  data_augmentation_options {
    ssd_random_crop {
    }
  }
}

train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "D:/Code/Image/cctvmodel/tfrecordfinalALL/train2.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "D:/Code/Image/cctvmodel/label_map.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  num_examples: 8000
  # Note: The below line limits the evaluation process to 10 evaluations.
  # Remove the below line to evaluate indefinitely.
  max_evals: 10
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "D:/Code/Image/cctvmodel/tfrecordfinalALL/test2.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "D:/Code/Image/cctvmodel/label_map.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
```

How can one retrain only the last fully connected layer? Or does one freeze the upper layers/weight and retrain?

Note that in the pretrained model folder there is .pb file and a single checkpoint file as shown below:
[image]

I have found a link for [fine tuning at existing checkpoint](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/17522/fine-tuning-a-model-from-an-existing-checkpoint-with-tensorflow-slim). More details can be found here[link](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim). The  example code is :

```
$ DATASET_DIR=/tmp/flowers
$ TRAIN_DIR=/tmp/flowers-models/inception_v3
$ CHECKPOINT_PATH=/tmp/my_checkpoints/inception_v3.ckpt
$ python train_image_classifier.py \
    --train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} \
    --dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} \
    --dataset_name=flowers \
    --dataset_split_name=train \
    --model_name=inception_v3 \
    --checkpoint_path=${CHECKPOINT_PATH} \
    --checkpoint_exclude_scopes=InceptionV3/Logits,InceptionV3/AuxLogits \
    --trainable_scopes=InceptionV3/Logits,InceptionV3/AuxLogits
```

How should I set the checkpoints to ensure it trains the last fully connected layer?

Comment: Is this what the setting should be at checkpoint_exclude_scopes and trainable_scope python train_image_classifier.py 
--train_dir=${TRAIN_DIR} 
--dataset_dir=${DATASET_DIR} 
--dataset_name=cifar10 
--dataset_split_name=train 
--model_name=nasnet_mobile 
--checkpoint_path=${CHECKPOINT_PATH} 
--preprocessing_name=inception 
--clone_on_cpu=True 
--moving_average_decay=0.999 
--checkpoint_exclude_scopes=aux_7/aux_logits/FC,final_layer/FC 
--trainable_scopes=aux_7/aux_logits/FC,final_layer/FC   https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/slim

Comment: Typically for fine-tuning one only want train a sub-set of layers, so the flag --trainable_scopes allows to specify which subsets of layers should trained, the rest would remain frozen.

Comment: did it worked out? if yes, how to get the layer names that we wanna include or exclude. can you pls guide me on this im also looking to train only the final layer and leave the rest frozen in SSD mobilenet